# Javascript confusion over variables defined by reference vs value

Tags: javascript, variables, pass-by-reference

I understand the following property of the javascript language:

```
var bar = 1;
var foo = bar;
bar = "something entirely different";
// foo is still 1
```

However, when trying to apply this logic to an object it seems to act differently:

```
var bar = {};
bar.prop = 1;
var foo = bar;
bar.prop = "something entirely different";
// foo.prop now changes to "something entirely different"
// but...
bar = "no longer an object";
// now foo remains an object with the prop property
```

Can someone tell me what's happening and why there is a difference?

Comment: I may have answered my own question:
"Javascript is always pass by value, but when a variable refers to an object (including arrays), the "value" is a reference to the object."
But this is still confusing, can someone explain more?

Comment: See my answer Jeff, please let me know if that makes any sense?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java pass by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: That question is relevant because nothing about your question is JavaScript specific.

Comment: @MikeSamuel You can't perform the above code snippets in Java, you will get an error. I would say the use of JavaScript code in reference to what was confusing him would make this question about JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. When you assign a variable to an object, you're really creating a second reference to that object. In the first case, what you're doing is assigning `bar` to point at the string `foo` points to, but then you *change* what `bar` points to when you reassign `bar`.

In the second example, you assign `bar` to a new object, then you point `foo` at that same object, then you reassign `bar` to a string. `foo` is still pointed at the same object.

Think of it like this: `bar = "something"` is *changing what `bar` points to*, not changing the actual object `{}` to a string.

[This article](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass) is a fairly good explanation of what you're seeing. I'm looking for even better / more authoritative references, however.

Comment: This is what I was going to say, the memory containing the object `bar` was assigned to is not erased and replaced with `"no longer an object"` but the reference is dropped (and if it had not other references it would be queued for garbage collection).

Answer (score 1):

Let's take it line by line:

```
var foo = bar;
```

All that names of objects do is hold addresses in memory. So in this statement, you are making `foo` hold the same memory address as `bar`. If for example `bar` was holding 0xFF, then via the assignment you would make `foo` also hold 0xFF.

However, keep in mind that `bar` and `foo` are two distinct objects, they happen to just hold the same address in memory.

Now, since they do happen to hold the same address in memory, mutating members of `bar` will also affect the members of `foo` because they are bound to the same object.

```
bar.prop = "something entirely different";  // affects foo.prop also
```

However, here is the key point to remember:

`Assignment only changes what the name of the object is bound to, and does not affect any other objects.`

In other words, the statement below made `bar` hold a different memory address, but this does not affect `foo`.

```
bar = "no longer an object"; // Made bar hold a different memory address
```

Now, explaining the quote:

`Javascript is always pass by value, but when a variable refers to an object (including arrays), the "value" is a reference to the object.`

Take this example:

```
function f(obj1, obj2)
{
    obj1.prop = 10;
    obj2 = {prop: 20};
}

var bar = {prop: 1};
var foo = {prop: 2};
f(bar, foo);
console.log("bar.prop: " + bar.prop + ", foo.prop: " + foo.prop);
```

This prints outs: `bar.prop: 10, foo.prop: 2`. Inside function `f`, obj1 holds the same memory address as `bar` and obj2 holds the same memory address as `foo`. However, only bar is affected because inside `f` only altering members of objects are reflected and assignment `obj2 = {prop: 20};` only affects the local variable `obj2` not `foo`.

In other words, `the "value" is a reference to an object` means, altering members affects the *referenced* object but assigning only affects the local variable.

Comment: I think that is the most confusing explanation I've seen. Forget all about memory and addresses, ECMA-262 specifies behaviour, not implementation.

Comment: @RobG: I think concrete rather than the abstract makes more sense to me (which was what I was trying to do), but thanks for the comment (I realize this way may not be appropriate for everyone). However, more *specific* comments would be more beneficial for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code you define the Var bar as variable.

in the second code you define it as an object.

The variables take a place in the memory;so when you define foo from bar its will be the same type as variable and will reserve a new memory location; and when you use equal operator you are replacing the data content of this variable.

The object in the second sample code on initialize will point (as pointer) to a memory location that will contain the data of this object; and when you define foo from bar its will be the same type as object and will point to the same memory location; so changing one of these two reference object value will reflect on the other one.